# UiDevice.getUiAutomation(instrumentation) returns null causing NPE, in Robolectric test

Tags: robolectric, android-uiautomator

In my Roblectric test, I try to confirm permission dialog with `UiDevice`

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner::class)
@Config(sdk = [Build.VERSION_CODES.P])
open class FooTest {

  @Before
  private fun before() {

    var device = UiDevice.getInstance(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation())

    // Confirm permissions dialog with device object
    // ...
  }
```

but this line throws an NPE exception

```
var device = UiDevice.getInstance(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation())
```

with stack trace

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at androidx.test.uiautomator.QueryController.<init>(QueryController.java:95)
at androidx.test.uiautomator.UiDevice.<init>(UiDevice.java:109)
at androidx.test.uiautomator.UiDevice.getInstance(UiDevice.java:261)
```

because `UiDevice.getUiAutomation(instrumentation)` is returning null

```
public QueryController(Instrumentation instrumentation) {
    mInstrumentation = instrumentation;
    UiDevice.getUiAutomation(instrumentation).setOnAccessibilityEventListener(mEventListener);
}
```

Comment: Any solution on this?

Comment: Same issue here, seems like you cannot get the instrumentation from here, you need to run in androidTest folder or get from the adb.